# How to customize the statusbar_visible display of the state field in odoo 16

Tags: python, xml, state, display, odoo-16

I have inherited view of mrp.production and write xpath as follows

```py
  <xpath expr="//header//field[@name='state']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="statusbar_visible">draft,to_approve,approved,rejected</attribute>
  </xpath>
```

when creating a new record I will leave statusbar_visible = draft, to_approve, approved, rejected
but when the record has state = approved then I want statusbar_visible = draft, confirmed, progress, done, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 2 mutually exclusive field definitions like:

```xml
<xpath expr="//header//field[@name='state']" position="attributes">
  <attribute name="statusbar_visible">draft,to_approve,rejected</attribute>
  <attribute name="attrs">{"invisible": [("state", "in", ["approved","confirmed","progress","done"])]}</attribute>
</xpath>
<xpath expr="//header//field[@name='state']" position="after">
  <field name="state" statusbar_visible="approved,confirmed,progress,done" attrs='{"invisible": [("state", "in", ["approved","confirmed","progress","done"])]}'/>
</xpath>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work

Comment: what happens? any error?